# How can I find if a value lies between two specific thresholds regardless of the order in which the thresholds are given?

Tags: python

For example, if I have a value `a = 4` and two input thresholds `t1 = 3` and `t2 = 5`.

`a > t1` and `a < t2` so the function `func(a, t1, t2)` returns true.

But if I input `t1 = 5` and `t2 = 3`, even if `a = 4` lies between the `t1` and `t2`, the function returns false. How to solve this?

So far I write this function in this way, but it only works when `t1 < t2`. Is there some smart way to do this?

```
def func(a, t1, t2):
    if a > t1 and a < t2:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `or`:

```py
def func(a, t1, t2):
    return t1 < a < t2 or t2 < a < t1

print(func(4, 3, 5)) # True
print(func(4, 5, 3)) # True
print(func(4, 1, 2)) # False
```

Note that python allows [chained comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) so that you don't need to write `t1 < a and a < t2`. Also, you don't need the redundant `if` statement as in:

```py
if t1 < a < t2 or t2 < a < t1:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

You could order the two thresholds before using them in the comparison with `a`, for example by using the `sorted` function:

```
smaller, larger = sorted([t1, t2])
```

If `t1 <= t2` then `smaller` will be `t1` and `larger` will be `t2`, otherwise `smaller` will be `t2` and `larger` will be `t1`.

```
def func(a, t1, t2):
    smaller, larger = sorted([t1, t2])
    return smaller < a < larger
```